# A conjectured identity for the fractional iterates of $\sqrt{x}+2$

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, conjectures, fractional-iteration

Deeply impressed by the [Fractional iterates of $x²-2$, a problem by Ramanujan](http://dmishin.blogspot.com/2018/11/fractional-iterates-of-x-2-problem-by.html) post one month ago, I decided to investigate a little by myself on the topic and discovered that using [Carleman matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix) would be of great help for that purpose.

After various numerical computations, and helped by several algorithms for recognizing patterns and guessing formulas, I finally came accross a differential equation detected in a Carleman matrix (by the [`guessHolo`](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/GuessingFormulasForSequences) function in the [FriCAS](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/) computer algebra system) which I could easily solve in order to write down the following identity:

$$
F^{[n]}(x) = 2 + 2\cosh\left(2^{1-n}\,\textrm{arcsinh}\!\left(\frac
  {\sqrt{x-4}}{2}\right)\right)
$$

with $F(x) = \sqrt{x} + 2$. Plotting this function for various values of $n$ between $1$ and $2$ together with the functions $F$ and $F^{[2]}$ shows how smoothly the interpolation works.

Now, I don't know if this is something trivial or not and would be very happy to learn about it. Is such a result already known?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=2(1+\cos\theta_n)$.  Then

$a_{n+1}=2+\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta_n)}=2+\sqrt{4\cos^2(\theta_n/2)}=2(1+\cos(\theta_n/2))$

using the familiar half angle formula for cosine.  By comparison

$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_n/2$

and thence

$\theta_n=2^{-n}\theta_0$

which is easily "fractionated".  We have to define a "principal value" of $\theta_0$, such as placing it in the interval $[0,\pi]$ for real values ($0\le a_0 \le 4$), in order to keep things single-valued.